# MongoDB -- client.open() returns "undefined in not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Here's what I have:

```js
var express = require('express');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var app = express();

var client = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017, {}), {});

client.open(function(err, client){
//callback
});
```

And when I run it, it points to the line the open method is on and says "undefined is not a function". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you follow the docs, does it say you should require the same module twice like that ?

Comment: What happens when you use `client.connect()` instead of `client.open()`?

Comment: Refer to the [**documentation**](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#open) for more guidelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [mongo docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/) :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

  db.close();
});
```

Comment: Figured out my problem. The book I was following instructions on was using 1.4. I had 2.0 installed.